# Add a plus minus icon in tr

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a + , - icon in a tr . Below is the code, I use for for expanding and collapsing the table tr/td.

```
// Click handler to show / hide the details rows when they are available

$(dt.table().body())
    .on('click.dtr mousedown.dtr mouseup.dtr', selector, function(e) {
        // If the table is not collapsed (i.e. there is no hidden columns)
        // then take no action
        if (!$(dt.table().node()).hasClass('collapsed')) {
            return;
        }
        // Check that the row is actually a DataTable's controlled node
        if ($.inArray($(this).closest('tr').get(0), dt.rows().nodes().toArray()) === -1) {
            return;
        }
        // For column index, we determine if we should act or not in the
        // handler - otherwise it is already okay
        if (typeof target === 'number') {
            var targetIdx = target < 0 ?
                dt.columns().eq(0).length + target :
                target;
            if (dt.cell(this).index().column !== targetIdx) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // $().closest() includes itself in its check
        var row = dt.row($(this).closest('tr'));
        // Check event type to do an action
        if (e.type === 'click') {
            // The renderer is given as a function so the caller can execute it
            // only when they need (i.e. if hiding there is no point is running
            // the renderer)
            that._detailsDisplay(row, false);
        } else if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
            // For mouse users, prevent the focus ring from showing
            $(this).css('outline', 'none');
        } else if (e.type === 'mouseup') {
            // And then re-allow at the end of the click
            $(this).blur().css('outline', '');
        }
    });
```

I have added the following code along with the respective css

// Add event listener for opening and closing details

```
 $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

However I am unable to display the results.

Comment: Do you have empty <th> and <td> elements as in the example here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Yes Sir. Something similar to that.Thank you

Comment: The table has a class named 'dataTable' and the tr has classes named 'odd' and 'even' alternatively

Comment: <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
<td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"> </td>
<td>some name</td>
<td>desc</td><td>text </td>
<td>60hours</td></tr>

This is the html format it renders

Comment: Is this jQuery? Could you add appropriate tags?

Comment: @Pavlo you are referring which code Sir?